# Why would a hosting provider not allow SSL over port 443?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl

I am setting up a website and bought the SSL certificate for the domain of the website. When I asked the hosting company why `https://www.example.com` was refusing connections, they answered that SSL access was configured on port 41696. Of course, `https://www.example.com:41696` works as they promised, but that's really not a URL I'd like to use for a customer facing website.

The hosting company also said that they can't change it to 443 even if we get a different package. I have never heard that from any other hosting providers I worked with. Is there a good reason why they are not letting that happen? Or is there any configuration that I can change on the server that will make it accept HTTPS requests on port 443?

Comment: There is no good reason for that. Do not give them any money, and go find another provider.

Comment: Concur. No good reasons to do this, several very good reasons *not* to. That said, I'd love to hear their explanation for it...

Comment: Sounds like they're idiots - please feel free to name and shame them so that others don't make the same selection mistake you did. Seriously.

Comment: Please see [my answer on this other post](http://serverfault.com/a/735040/255167) for additional reasons why serving a public-facing HTTPS site over a non-standard port is a terrible, terrible idea. Definitely switch hosting providers.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question hasn't been closed. It's not about system administration. Why $unnamedcompany does $thing can only reasonably be answered by $unnamedcompany. Everything else is guessing and we don't do that here.

Comment: @Iain So...close it now?

Comment: Sounds like they can't configure PAT or have some translation complications. Either way for a web hosting company it's poor.

Comment: @gf_ I cast the 2nd vote hours ago.

Comment: Disagree with vote to close; the question isn't why $unnamedcompany does $thing. The question is do valid reasons exist for a provider to do $thing. And that definitely sounds sysadmin related to me.

Comment: @Chopper3 the hosting provider is a Korean company called cafe24.com.  The website will be serving customers in South Korea only, that's why we wanted to go with this provider.

Comment: @David the only people who know why the $company are doing this are $company. Everything else is idle speculation.

Comment: @Iain. Agreed, but as I said, the question, ultimately, isn't about why that particular company is doing $thing. The question is about **whether valid reasons exist** for any company to do $thing.

Comment: @Iain Would it be better if I rephrase the question to "Are there valid reasons for a hosting provider to not allow SSL over port 443?" ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Historically, HTTPS [required a dedicated IP per site/certificate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/13992), since the browser needs to verify the certificate before sending the `Host` header. It's possible that your hosting provider uses dedicated ports instead, in order to conserve IPs.

Nowadays, however, pretty much all modern browsers support [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which allows virtual hosting multiple HTTPS sites on the same IP and port, so even that isn't a particularly good reason anymore. If this is a shared hosting service, it's unlikely that there are any config changes you can make to make your site be available on the default port.

Comment: This is it. :) There is nothing weird with that, just an old provider with its old limitations. Switch your provider and get you certificate renewed.

Comment: @Daniel In my opinion doing this in 2016 is 'weird'. The corresponding [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt) dates back to June 2003 (!) These are _thirteen years_. (Yes, I know that it takes some time between doing requests for comments and the actual implementation, but if this is the reason the environment of the provider looks like it does, then this is way too much time (in my opinion).)

Comment: Just to add for completeness, SNI is supported by all major browsers, but many business tools, older app servers and even some modern libraries do not properly support SNI.  Be sure to research this and get the facts based on your specific use case.

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr:** Switch the provider, this one seems a bit weird.

---

> Is there a good reason why they are not letting that happen?

Depends on what one thinks is "a good reason", but in my opinion: No.

> Or is there any configuration that I can change on the server that will make it accept https requests on port 443?

If the provider is blocking / filtering access, sadly, you can't do anything about this on your side.

Answer (score 7):

Possible explanation:

There are at least some providers who sell you virtual machines which have their distinct IPV6 addresses, but a shared IPV4 address. One example is [this](https://quadhost.net/virtual-private-server/budget-vps/) (this link should in no way be seen as an endorsement or advertisement). You typically get a few port forwards, but thery're TCP based (no SNI, HTTP host header or anything), so the port number is the only way to select "your" host.

With IPV4 addresses becoming rarer and rarer, this is one way of saving on them.

If the website is for a charity or similar organization which has few funds, and you absolutely have to stick to the lowest price possible, you can probably set up a free cloudflare plan that forwards your-domain.com:443 to your 41696 port.

If not, get a different hoster.

Comment: Cloudflare won't do the port forwarding.

Comment: It is easy to forward HTTPS with SNI in this scenario (e.g. with haproxy); if the provider does not do so then they are either lazy or incompetent. Either way you don't want to give them your money.

Comment: I guess if I offered a vps at £2.50 *annually*, i'd be too lazy to do any customer-specific configuration as well. Of course, such a vps is arguably not a good platform for a company website that has any reliability requirements. So agree: run your website elsewhere.

Comment: @CanadianLuke but if you give cloudflare only the IPv6 IP, they will do the IPv4->IPv6 forwarding.